A unexpected behavior about draw circle with the radius in meters with mapbox gl js
I attempted to achieve drawing a circle with the radius in miles meters with mapbox gl js.
At first glance，it works well. But an unexpected behavior occurred when i drag and zoom the map near the boundary: the circle disappearing or appearing inexplicably
view image
Why does this problem occur? How can I solve this problem?
Primary Code
"circle-radius": [
  "interpolate",
  ["exponential", 2],
  ["zoom"],
  0,
  0,
  22,
  [
    "/",
    ["/", ["get", "radius"], 0.019],
    ["cos", ["/", ["*", ["get", "lat"], ["pi"]], 180]],
  ],
],

Example Live
Everything goes well!
